# How to apply validation to customer address edit details in customer_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, validation

I want to validate the customers forms using the .xml UI validation.

Comment: can you please add your code here?so that will be easy to understand your problem.

Comment: I checkout page for validation I have added the below code in the checkout_index_index.xml page {<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
     <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item></item>
</item> }

Comment: The same thing I have to apply to the customer forms validation also

Comment: try my answer's code.let me know if still facing the same issue.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code**

```
<!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <field name="postcode" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                </settings>
      </field>
```

**I hope it help..!!!**