# add or edit address validation

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add validation to address fields. I have successfully achieved my requirement in checkout_index_index.xml for shipping address.

I want to have server side Validation to allow alpha-number-space in customer and checkout modules.

I have used following code for checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>                                                            
                                                                    <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="numeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="numeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="numeric" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have gone through [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255563/how-to-apply-validation-to-customer-address-edit-details-in-customer-index-index) but I din't get how to do so.

Please guide me to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference link](https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-custom-fields-customer-address-magento-2/)

For this, you need to add a custom field in **customer_address_form.xml** file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::address/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml** file and paste in **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml** file

add a custom field in this file like this:

```
<div class="field customfield">
            <label class="label" for="business_number">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */
                    $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('business_number') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="business_number"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($businessNumber) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */
                       $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('business_number') ?>"
                       id="business_number">
            </div>
        </div>
```

here I added custom attribute **business_number** so you need to replace bussines_number with your custom attribute

Let me know if you face any issues.

**Thank You**

Comment: this solution is to add new field to address where I need validations for existing feilds

Comment: data-validate='{"minlength":3} you can add validation like this in edit.phtml file

Comment: can you suggest server side validation and also for widget/name.phtml. i have tried name.phtml but i am unable to figure it out

Comment: i think server side validation would be good idea.

Comment: I overide widget/name.phtml. now just need server validation to validate only to allow alpha-num-space

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please share some more details, what kind of validations you want. I applied validations in the address at the checkout and admin.**

- You should use Jquery that will be the best fit for you.

  For the Admin Panel you can use the UI component Validations

Answer (score 0):

**1.For add new validation or Modify for Contact Information on address book (Contact Information section only)**

Magento 2 First name and Last name is default customer entity available in Native Magento. Once you install Magento 2, Customer first name and last name attribute available.

> Firstname and Lastname attribute available with Customer and
> Customer_address entity type.

- **customer entity** type contains attribute used for registration page and customer form related entity.
- **customer_address entity** types used for billing and shipping form of customer.

You can do it server-side validation and client-side validation using below link.

[Validate First name & Last name](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-set-firstname-and-lastname-with-minimum-character-required-in-magento-2/)

**Note :** in the above link they give an example of giving limit validation. you have to add validation as per your requirement.

**2.You need to overright vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml to modify or add new validation for customer address book (address section only) as per your requirements**

[image: edit.phtml]

Here is the list of validation which you can use

- **required-entry:**

  This is a required field.
- **validate-alphanum-with-spaces:**

  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.
- **phoneUK:**

  Please specify a valid phone number
- **validate-email:**

  Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).
- **ipv4:**

  Please enter a valid IP v4 address.
- **checked:**

  This is a required field.
- **validate-select:**

  Please select an option.
- **ipv6:**

  Please enter a valid IP v6 address.
- **time:**

  Please enter a valid time, between 00:00 and 23:59
- **validate-number:**

  Please enter a valid number in this field.
- **validate-phoneLax:**

  Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.
- **dateITA:**

  Please enter a correct date
- **validate-xml-identifier:**

  Please enter a valid XML-identifier (Ex: something_1, block5, id-4).
- **validate-clean-url:**

  Please enter a valid URL. For example http://www.example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
- **validate-admin-password:**

  Please enter 7 or more characters, using both numeric and alphabetic.
- **validate-no-html-tags:**

  HTML tags are not allowed.
- **validate-integer:**

  Please enter a valid integer in this field.
- **validate-data:**

  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) in this field, and the first character should be a letter.
- **validate-cc-ukss:**

  Please enter issue number or start date for switch/solo card type.
- **min-words:**

  Please enter at least {0} words.
- **alphanumeric:**

  Letters, numbers, spaces or underscores only please
- **validate-identifier:**

  Please enter a valid URL Key (Ex: "example-page", "example-page.html" or "anotherlevel/example-page").
- **validate-street:**

  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9), spaces and "#" in this field.
- **validate-zip-international:**

  Please enter a valid zip code.
- **validate-date:**

  Please enter a valid date.
- **validate-greater-than-zero:**

  Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field.
- **validate-digits:**

  Please enter a valid number in this field.
- **validate-ssn:**

  Please enter a valid social security number (Ex: 123-45-6789).
- **not-negative-amount:**

  Please enter a positive number in this field.
- **validate-max-size:**

  File you are trying to upload exceeds maximum file size limit.
- **validate-fax:**

  Please enter a valid fax number (Ex: 123-456-7890).
- **validate-if-tag-script-exist:**

  Please use tag SCRIPT with SRC attribute or with proper content to include JavaScript to the document.
- **min_text_length:**

  Please enter more or equal than {0} symbols.
- **validate-date-au:**

  Please use this date format: dd/mm/yyyy. For example 17/03/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006.
- **mobileUK:**

  Please specify a valid mobile number
- **letters-with-basic-punc:**

  Letters or punctuation only please
- **validate-number-range:**

  The value is not within the specified range.
- **phoneUS:**

  Please specify a valid phone number
- **date_range_max:**

  The date is not within the specified range.
- **validate-range:**

  The value is not within the specified range.
- **vinUS:**

  The specified vehicle identification number (VIN) is invalid.
- **range-words:**

  Please enter between {0} and {1} words.
- **validate-zip-us:**

  Please enter a valid zip code (Ex: 90602 or 90602-1234).
- **validate-emails:**

  Please enter valid email addresses, separated by commas. For example, johndoe@domain.com, johnsmith@domain.com.
- **validate-css-length:**

  Please input a valid CSS-length (Ex: 100px, 77pt, 20em, .5ex or 50%).
- **zip-range:**

  Your ZIP-code must be in the range 902xx-xxxx to 905-xx-xxxx
- **validate-phoneStrict:**

  Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.
- **letters-only:**

  Letters only please
- **max_text_length:**

  Please enter less or equal than {0} symbols.
- **validate-not-negative-number:**

  Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.
- **validate-per-page-value-list:**

  Please enter a valid value, ex: 10,20,30
- **no-whitespace:**

  No white space please
- **validate-state:**

  Please select State/Province.
- **validate-url:**

  Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://).
- **date_range_min:**

  The date is not within the specified range.
- **validate-digits-range:**

  The value is not within the specified range.
- **greater-than-equals-to:**

  Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.
- **validate-no-empty:**

  Empty Value.
- **validate-zero-or-greater:**

  Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.
- **validate-cc-number:**

  Please enter a valid credit card number.
- **validate-emailSender:**

  Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).
- **validate-new-password:**

  Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **validate-customer-password:**

  Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **validate-password:**

  Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.
- **less-than-equals-to:**

  Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}.
- **validate-currency-dollar:**

  Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.
- **time12h:**

  Please enter a valid time, between 00:00 am and 12:00 pm
- **validate-alphanum:**

  Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed.
- **validate-item-quantity:**

  We don't recognize or support this file extension type.
- **validate-code:**

  Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_) in this field, and the first character should be a letter.
- **email2:**

  Please enter a valid credit card number.
- **max-words:**

  Please enter {0} words or less.
- **stripped-min-length:**

  Please enter at least {0} characters
- **validate-alpha:**

  Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.
- **pattern:**

  Invalid format.
- **integer:**

  A positive or negative non-decimal number, please

You can add you custom validation also,
[custom validation](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-validation-checkout/)

*Hope it helps...!!*