# How to set a date field in a ui form to be mandatory?

Tags: validation, form-validation, date, datepicker

I have this date field in a form (a ui component) and i'm tryig to make it "required field", I tried with `<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>` but it didn't work. And also tried with a custom validation but also not working, any ideas?

Date field in the form

```
        <field name="date_of_birth" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Date of birth</item>
                </item>     
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                    <item name="date-required-custom" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>    
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>timestamp</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date of birth</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>date_of_birth</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

Custom validation (I currently have more rules and they work)

```
require([
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
    'jquery'
], function (validator, $) {
    validator.addRule(
        'date-required-custom',
        function (value) {
            if (!(value == null || value === 'undefined')) {
                return false;
            };
        }
        ,$.mage.__('Field required.')
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace below code for required date field:

```
<field name="date_of_birth">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date of birth</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">date_of_birth</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">string</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

And for your custom validation or another validation, you can see the below link,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/363768/110348

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, this will work :

```
    <field name="display_from" sortOrder="60" formElement="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Display From</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>timestamp</dataType>
            <dataScope>display_from</dataScope>
            <label translate="true">From</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
```